# How does gensim word2vec word embedding extract training word pair for 1 word sentence?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

Refer to below image (the process of how word2vec skipgram extract training datasets-the word pair from the input sentences).

E.G. "I love you." ==> [(I,love), (I, you)]

May I ask what is the word pair when the sentence contains only one word?

Is it  "Happy!" ==> [(happy,happy)] ?

I tested the word2vec algorithm in genism, when there is just one word in the training set sentences, (and this word is not included in other sentences), the word2vec algorithm can still construct an embedding vector for this specific word. I am not sure how the algorithm is able to do so.

[image]

===============UPDATE===============================

As the answer posted below, I think the word embedding vector created for the word in the 1-word-sentence is just the random initialization of neural network weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No word2vec training is possible from a 1-word sentence, because there's no neighbor words to use as input to predict a center/target word. Essentially, that sentence is skipped.

If that was the only appearance of the word in the corpus, and you're seeing a vector for that word, it's just the starting random-initialization of the word, with no further training. (And, you should probably use a higher `min_count`, as keeping such rare words is usually a mistake in word2vec: they won't get good vectors, and other nearby words' vectors will improve if the 'noise' from all such insufficiently model-able rare words is removed.)

If that 1-word sentence actually appeared next-to other real sentences in your corpus, it could make sense to combine it with surrounding texts. There's nothing magic about actual sentences for this kind word-from-surroundings modeling - the algorithm is just working on 'neighbors', and it's common to use multi-sentence chunks as the texts for training, and sometimes even punctuation (like sentence-ending periods) is also retained as 'words'. Then words from an actually-separate sentence – but still related by having appeared in the same document – will appear in each other's contexts.